# importing bootstrap in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to build the web using VueJs with Bootstrap but whenever I add the Bootstrap imports, the website goes blank. Even when I add the bootstrap components, it is blank too. Could anyone guide me please?

Here is my imports on main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

App.use(BootstrapVue)
createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

My App.vue

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light"> -- this is the bootstrap components
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <form class="d-flex">
      <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav> --- bootstrap components

</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: First thing would be to see if you have any errors in your browser's console. Then, double-checking that your version of bootstrap is working with your version of Vue could be a nice thing. Reading [the docs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs#vue-cli-3), it's also written to import the thing as `import { BootstrapVue } from 'bootstrap-vue'` and not as you're currently doing. The rest should be working fine. Here, it's a matter of finding the proper documentation + debug with the errors provided to you in the given tools (browser console here mainly).

Comment: Also you're not using Bootstrap 5 directly. So I removed the tag in favor of `bootstrap-vue`. Whatever what is behind, it is not our focus for an initial configuration of the project with Vue.

Comment: I got this error in console. 

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'version')
    at eval (vue.js?b4e2:17:1)
    at ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js (chunk-vendors.js:3417:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:208:33)
    at fn (app.js:441:21)
    at eval (events.js:66:62)
    at ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/constants/events.js (chunk-vendors.js:2372:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:208:33)
    at fn (app.js:441:21)
    at eval (alert.js:9:76)
    at ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/components/alert/alert.js (chunk-vendors.js:84:1)`

Comment: This is not really readable since it's in a comment. Also, I'm not sure how that one may be useful. Do you use the `Alert` component somewhere? Some more context as of your configuration may be highly welcome here. Or even a [repro] or a public github link.

Comment: No, I didn't use Alert. I got it from the browser console. Have a look [here](https://imgur.com/a/VpYiyFc)

Comment: The rest of my previous comment is still valid. A single screenshot with just the result, will not help us going forward.

Comment: All good. Your previous comments was helpful. I have successfully implemented it with version Vue 2. I did it with Vue 3 previously.

Comment: Nice! A posted an answer since it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP achieved a working setup by using Vue2 as somewhat suggested here: [importing bootstrap in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74540534/importing-bootstrap-in-vuejs?noredirect=1#comment131581253_74540534)